# iterate over associative array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this table of objects:

```
var gridRegions = {
  seattle:         { label: "SEA", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [125.00, 117.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  great_falls:     { label: "GTF", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [117.00, 109.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  billings:        { label: "BIL", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [109.00, 101.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  twin_cities:     { label: "MSP", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [101.00,  93.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  green_bay:       { label: "GRB", lats: [48.25, 44.00], lons: [ 93.00,  85.00], numGrids: 544, gridLabels: [] }, 
  lake_huron:      { label: "LHN", lats: [48.00, 44.00], lons: [ 85.00,  77.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  montreal:        { label: "MON", lats: [48.00, 44.00], lons: [ 77.00,  69.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  halifax:         { label: "HFX", lats: [48.00, 44.00], lons: [ 69.00,  61.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  klamath_falls:   { label: "LMT", lats: [44.50, 40.00], lons: [125.00, 117.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  salt_lake_city:  { label: "SLC", lats: [44.50, 40.00], lons: [117.00, 109.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  cheyenne:        { label: "LMT", lats: [44.50, 40.00], lons: [109.00, 101.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  omaha:           { label: "OMA", lats: [44.50, 40.00], lons: [101.00,  93.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  chicago:         { label: "ORD", lats: [44.00, 40.00], lons: [ 93.00,  85.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  detroit:         { label: "DET", lats: [44.00, 40.00], lons: [ 85.00,  77.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  new_york:        { label: "NYC", lats: [44.00, 40.00], lons: [ 77.00,  69.00], numGrids: 512, gridLabels: [] },
  san_francisco:   { label: "SFO", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [125.00, 118.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  las_vegas:       { label: "LAS", lats: [40.00, 35.75], lons: [118.00, 111.00], numGrids: 476, gridLabels: [] },
  denver:          { label: "DEN", lats: [40.00, 35.75], lons: [111.00, 104.00], numGrids: 476, gridLabels: [] },
  wichita:         { label: "ICT", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [104.00,  97.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  kansas_city:     { label: "MKC", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [ 97.00,  90.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  st_louis:        { label: "STL", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [ 91.00,  84.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  cincinnati:      { label: "LUK", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [ 85.00,  78.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  washington:      { label: "DCA", lats: [40.00, 36.00], lons: [ 79.00,  72.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  los_angeles:     { label: "LAX", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [121.50, 115.00], numGrids: 416, gridLabels: [] },
  phoenix:         { label: "PHX", lats: [35.75, 31.25], lons: [116.00, 109.00], numGrids: 504, gridLabels: [] },
  albuquerque:     { label: "ABQ", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [109.00, 102.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  dallas_ft_worth: { label: "DFW", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [102.00,  95.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  memphis:         { label: "MEM", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [ 95.00,  88.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  atlanta:         { label: "ATL", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [ 88.00,  81.00], numGrids: 448, gridLabels: [] },
  charlotte:       { label: "CLT", lats: [36.00, 32.00], lons: [ 81.00,  75.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  el_paso:         { label: "ELP", lats: [32.00, 28.00], lons: [109.00, 103.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  san_antonio:     { label: "SAT", lats: [32.00, 28.00], lons: [103.00,  97.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  houston:         { label: "HOU", lats: [32.00, 28.00], lons: [ 97.00,  91.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  new_orleans:     { label: "MSY", lats: [32.00, 28.00], lons: [ 91.00,  85.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  jacksonville:    { label: "JAX", lats: [32.00, 28.00], lons: [ 85.00,  79.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  brownsville:     { label: "BRO", lats: [28.00, 24.00], lons: [103.00,  97.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] },
  miami:           { label: "MIA", lats: [28.00, 24.00], lons: [ 83.00,  77.00], numGrids: 384, gridLabels: [] }
};
```

In the main usage, the user selects the region of interest by region name and I'm able to access the object contents for a region by gridRegions['name'].val

What I'm trying to do at startup is to iterate thru the entire list and dynamically add html to the empty array gridLabels based on the value of numGrids for that entry. I have tried every combination of

```
Object.keys(gridRegions).forEach((region, label) =>  {
  console.log('grid region: ', region );
  console.log('Object.entries ', Object.entries(region));
});
Object.entries(gridRegions).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
});
Object.forEach((region) => {
  console.log(region.label);
  console.log(region[label]);
  console.log(region['label']);
})
```

But I can't get past only being able to access the region name. Everything else is undefined.
    What I'd like to do is

```
gridRegions.forEach((region) => {
  for (i = 0; i < region.numGrids; i++)
    gridLabels[i] = region.label + i.pad(3);
}
```

Is there a secret here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `gridRegions.forEach` at the end? It looks like it should work. Do, note you as missing a `);` at the end of your code example.

Comment: it should be noted that `Object.keys` requires IE 9 or newer, which should be fine for most use cases. otherwise, you might consider using jQuery's `$.each()`

Comment: Why not just use `for (var regionName of gridRegions) { var region = gridRegions[regionName]; console.log(regionName, region.label); … }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach`'s arguments are the array element (in this case, a key) and the array index. If you want to get the object referenced by the key, you have to access it with `[]` first *if you're using forEach*:

```
Object.keys(gridRegions).forEach((region) => {
  const obj = gridRegions[region];
  console.log(obj.label);
```

Or you can use Object.entries to start with, which iterates over an objects properties and property values at once:

```js
const gridRegions = {
  seattle:         { label: "SEA", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [125.00, 117.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
  great_falls:     { label: "GTF", lats: [49.00, 44.50], lons: [117.00, 109.00], numGrids: 576, gridLabels: [] },
};
Object.entries(gridRegions).forEach(([key, obj]) => {
  console.log(`${key} : ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
});
```

Comment: This was magic I was missing! Thanks, have it working like a charm now!

Comment: The `Object.entries` trick remindes me of Python's `enumerate(list)`. Keep in mind, this does not work at all in IE and Safari mobile. See: [Object.entries() - Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: for an index could you not just add a second parameter to the forEach? e.g. `Object.keys(gridRegions).forEach((region, index) => { ... })`